# How to format JSON object PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create a POST to a REST API to create a new object. I cannot figure out how to properly format my JSON.

Here's the response from the GET of an existing object:

```
{
    "name": "product 2 mem"
    "type": "simple"
    "categories": array:1 [▼
    0 => {
      "id": 75
    }
    ]
    "meta_data": array:1 [▼
      "id": 3665
      "key": "_yith_wcbm_product_meta"
      "value": {
        "id_badge": "2955"
      }
    }
    ]
  }
```

Here is the POST I'm trying to create:

```
    $data = [
        'name' => 'product name',
        'type' => 'simple',
        'categories' => [
            [
                'id' => 75
            ],
        'meta_data' => [ 
            '_yith_wcbm_product_meta' => [
                'id_badge' => '2955'
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: Can you share some more details? What would you like to achieve? Do you want to parse or generate JSON?

Comment: have you tried `json_decode` function for this `json`?

Comment: @Screeper I am trying to create the JSON object to post. Everything works except the metadata. So I am formatting it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to format it:

```
        'meta_data' => [ 
            [
                'key' => '_yith_wcbm_product_meta',
                'value' => ['id_badge' => '2955']
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You got typo in you json data.

```
$response = '{
  "id": 3665,
  "key": "_yith_wcbm_product_meta",
  "value": {
    "id_badge": "2955"
    }
    }';
$array = json_decode($response,true);

$return  = ['meta_data'=>['key'=>$array['key'],'value'=>$array['value']]];

echo json_encode($return);
```